# What is the correct pronunciation for "forever"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

What is the correct pronunciation for the word "forever"? In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l67b1HBvtxo) I found it sounds like /fəˈevər/ but in dictionaries it is /fəˈrevər/. I believe there are many other examples like this word, but I can only come up with this one right now.

Comment: https://forvo.com/word/forever/#en

Comment: By "correct" pronunciation, do you mean according to standard American English (meaning the American accent which is features on mainstream national entertainment television)? There is, after all, no "correct" way to pronounce anything; it always depends on the speaker's accent.

Comment: Regardless of accent, "forever" is typically spoken as world be the component words, since "forever" is a compound of "for" and "ever". "Forever" is therefore pronounced just so. "For ever." Though the specific pronunciation of each of those words may vary by accent.

Comment: I can't think of someone **not** pronouncing the first *r* in *forever* - it's actually shifted from the first to the second syllable, and the second *r* **is** silent: /fəˈrɛvə/ ( https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/forever )

Comment: @RMac Your source?

Comment: Etymology sourced originally from my own study and pronunciation sourced from frequent occurrence of this word in all contexts of speech and a lifetime inability to escape this bloody language. The second `r` is typically not silent. Ask a dozen native speakers of SAE to speak the written word and you will find that `r` is spoken. https://www.etymonline.com/word/forever https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/forever

Comment: The Lexico dictionary page linked by @Kris describes BrE, not AmE.

Comment: Hi @RMac, thanks. It seems I need to learn more about pronunciation... I even didn't know how to pronounce the second _r_. I just pronounced the word as /fə/ + /re/ + /və/ before.

Comment: **us** /fɔːˈrev.ɚ/ https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forever ; **forever in American** 
(fɔrˈɛvər ; fərˈɛvər ) https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/forever Also @RMac